# RStudio can't knit results that are in scientific notation

Tags: r, r-markdown

This code produces a nice PDF upon clicking "knit" in RStudio:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

My favorite number is `r 1 - 0.999`
````

But the following code produces an error

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

My favorite number is `r 1 - 0.9999`
````

The error produced:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.85 My favorite number is 10\times

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

It looks like it's because the output of `1 - 0.999` is `0.001` but the output of `1 - 0.9999` is `1e-04`, a different representation. What can be done?

Comment: Can you disable scientific notation prior to running this, with options(scipen = 999)

Comment: @caw5cv Yes, that works, thanks. That's a good workaround if it turns out there's no way to get things like `1e-04` to render.

Answer (score 1):

What about one of these guys?

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

My favorite number is `r formatC(1 - 0.9999, format="s")`

My favorite number is `r as.character(1 - 0.9999)`

My favorite number is `r formatC(1 - 0.9999, format="g")`

My favorite number is `r as.character(round(1 - 0.9999, 5))`
```

***Yields:***

[image]